# Unit testing CDI with CDI-Unit Jglue

Tags: unit-testing, gradle, cdi, weld, cdi-unit

we want to use Jglue framework for unit testing our CDI application. We use gradle for building.

We have prepared something like this:

1) Class to test:

```
@Default
public class RateTypeHibernateFactory implements RateTypeFactory {

@Override
public RateType getInstance(String name, String description) {
    RateType rateType = getInstance();
    rateType.setName(name);
    rateType.setDescription(description);
    return rateType;
}

}
```

2) Interface:

```
public interface RateTypeFactory {

public RateType getInstance(String name, String description);

}
```

3) Gradle settings (we followed getting started http://jglue.org/cdi-unit/)

```
dependencies {

     testCompile (group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.8.2')
     testCompile (group: 'org.jglue.cdi-unit', name: 'cdi-unit', version: '2.2.0')

}
```

4) Test class:

```
@RunWith(CdiRunner.class)
public class RateTypeFactoryTest {

@Inject RateTypeFactory rateTypeFactory;

@Test
public void testGetInstance() {
    RateType rateType = rateTypeFactory.getInstance();
    assertNotNull(rateType);
}

}
```

When we run this simple test, we always get this exception:

```
com.etnetera.projects.ticketing.model.factory.RateTypeFactoryTest > testGetInstance FAILED
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

1 test completed, 1 failed
:test FAILED
```

In /build/reports/tests/index.html there is:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.weld.metadata.BeansXmlImpl.<init>(Ljava/util/List;Ljava/util/List;Ljava/util/List;Ljava/util/List;Lorg/jboss/weld/bootstrap/spi/Scanning;Ljava/net/URL;Lorg/jboss/weld/bootstrap/spi/BeanDiscoveryMode;Ljava/lang/String;)V
at org.jglue.cdiunit.internal.WeldTestUrlDeployment.<init>(WeldTestUrlDeployment.java:80)
at org.jglue.cdiunit.CdiRunner$1.createDeployment(CdiRunner.java:71)
at org.jboss.weld.environment.se.Weld.initialize(Weld.java:137)
at org.jglue.cdiunit.CdiRunner.createTest(CdiRunner.java:82)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:258)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:255)
at org.jglue.cdiunit.CdiRunner.methodBlock(CdiRunner.java:113)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:55)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:42)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:71)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:49)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
at $Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:103)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:355)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:66)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Please does anybody know how to avoid this exception? I can add some more details if needed.

Comment: What version of weld are you running against?

Comment: My version of weld is 1.1.8.

Comment: 1.1.8 should work with 2.1.1
If you're still having issues then please raise a bug on the issue tracker: https://github.com/BrynCooke/cdi-unit/issues?state=open

Answer (score 1):

This is usually caused by an unsupported version of weld being used. 
However, I have just released CDI-Unit 2.2.1 which fixes a couple of issues with Gradle builds.
Please can you give it a go?

Comment: Also check out the Gradle sample project:
https://github.com/BrynCooke/cdi-unit/tree/master/cdi-unit-tests-gradle

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered a similar problem (with an error message a bit different). I googled a lot around this problem but did not found much about this, so I concluded that it was specific to my project. This lead me to suspect a version mismatch between the dependencies of the project.

I was using `weld-servlet: 2.4.0.Final` as a `compile` dependency and `cdi-unit: 3.1.4` as a `test` dependency. And I noticed that `cdi-unit` had a dependency on `weld-se-core: 2.3.2.Final`. So I added `weld-se-core` to my dependency management with the same version as my `weld-servlet` artifact and it solved the problem.

For further reference, here is an extract of my `pom.xml` file

```
<properties>
    <weld.version>2.4.0.Final</weld.version>
    <cdi-unit.version>3.1.4</cdi-unit.version>
    (...)
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- CDI -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${weld.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Tests -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jglue.cdi-unit</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-unit</artifactId>
            <version>${cdi-unit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-se-core</artifactId>
            <version>${weld.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        (...)
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <!-- CDI -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Tests -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jglue.cdi-unit</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-unit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    (...)
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are invoking a method on the interface without the parameters.
Instead of 
`RateType rateType = rateTypeFactory.getInstance();`
you should probably call
`RateType rateType = rateTypeFactory.getInstance("name", "description");`

Maybe I missed something gradle-related?